# Crash when calling MATLAB via engOpen in C/C++ with mingw-w64 on 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: c, matlab, mingw, 32bit-64bit, mingw-w64

I am trying to figure out why my C/C++ program crashes when I call MATLAB's engine with `engOpen()`. The code below  prints `Hello World` and then throws an `APPCRASH`.

What might be causing this crash, or how do I debug from here?

### testMATLAB.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "engine.h"

int main(){
printf("Hello World.\n");
    Engine *ep;
        if (!(ep = engOpen(NULL))) {
            printf("Can't start MATLAB engine\n");
        } else {
            printf("Opening Matlab Engine\n");
        }

return 0;
}
```

[image: The executable crashes at runtime after outputting "Hello World."]

### More Details

I am using:

- MATLAB R2012a
- mingw-w64 gcc version 4.8.0
- 64 bit Windows 7

In response to a number of existing SO Q&As, I have

- confirmed that I am linking to `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libeng.lib` and `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\libmx.lib`.
- included `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win64` in my path which contains `libengine.dll` and `libmx.dll`
- ran `matlab /regserver` from the windows command prompt

Note, if I place the `engOpen()` inside an `if` statement that isn't executed, then the code runs to completion.

I also do not think this is inherent to mingw because on a 32 bit WinXP machine I had no problem using MATLAB 2011 with `mingw32`.

Compiler and linker output is at http://pastebin.com/z9CAsb6X

Answer (score 0):

How did you link the *.lib? On my project I use PostgreSQL and instead of linking the provided MSVC-compiled *.lib I had to convert it to *.a. I think it was a procedure like this one:

http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/CreateImportLibraries

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading up on this. in the meantime, you can see the linker command I used on lines 97 and 98 of http://pastebin.com/z9CAsb6X

Comment: the link you sent seems to be for the case where the linker throws linking errors.  But in this case I get no linker errors. Do you think its still relevant?

Comment: For your link command: To link a library I normally use combination of -L and -l options, so I would put -LC:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/lib/
win64/microsoft/ -leng, but then I think the linker will throw you errors too...

Comment: If you search google for "gcc link msvc lib", so I think it is obvious that you should not expect *.lib files to be compatible with gcc.

Comment: Another howto similar to what I posted already: http://wyw.dcweb.cn/dllfaq.htm The problem is I would say, that they don't really convert *.lib to *.a but regenerate *.a from *.def extracted from *.lib/*.dll. I don't know whether you can convert arbitrary *.lib (that does not just encapsulate *.dll) into *.a.

Comment: Interesting. It would seem that reimp is 32 bit. In this thread, they suggest using `gendef` and `dlltools` for 64bit: http://www.mail-archive.com/mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01643.html  I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I link using those `DLL` directly rather than lib files, say: `libeng.dll, libut.dll, libmex.dll and libmat.dll`.

My setup is `MinGW 4.8.1 64bit, Win7 64bit, Matlab 64bit`.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Visual Studio. I think it has to do with the way Matlab 64 bit handles warnings after it closes. 
I had to add: (Mathworks solved my problem there)

```
warning('off','MATLAB:ClassInstanceExists') % Add this line
```

to my matlab code, which probably meant there was some matlab class that was not really needed in my code,
but still matlab compiler wanted to find? (my guess...)

If this does not work directly you might want to disable more warnings?...